Unable to access Openstack Instance via SSH
I deployed a new instance in my Openstack cluster and it's now running.
I de-attach the network interface from my old instance and attached it on the new one.
Previously I was able to connect via SSH to the old instance, but when I switch the network interface on the new one, I cannot access the new instance via SSH.
I also tried to switch the interface back to the old instance, and now even on the old one I cannot access via SSH.
The security groups are ok.
Thanks for any help :)

Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [su] or [unix.se]. When you do, you should describe exactly what happens when you try to connect. Do you get any error messages? What exactly do they say? Just saying you "can't access the new instance" is pretty vague.
